# Is there a way to display success messages in the "testing" package when writing unit test cases in Go?

Tags: go

I am using testing package to test my code. Currently I am only logging errors when errors are not 'nil' like:

```
if err != nil {
  t.Errorf("Failed to initialise Client %s", err)
}
```

I also want to print success messages when error is nil using the same `t *testing.T` instance. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [`t.Log()`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Log)? But it’s not very idiomatic.

Comment: `assert.NoError(t, err)`

Comment: Use t.Log or fmt.Println, but basically No, and you shouldn't.

Comment: Note that such stuff typically is done outside: Use `go test && echo "Success"` if for some reasons you need to have a success message (instead of the proper exit code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Log or Logf methods:

```
t.Log("It works like Println")
t.Logf("It works like Printf")
```

Check [official documents](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#pkg-index) for more details.